# is it possible to download planet files of OpenSeaMap data?

Tags: android, openseamap

I want to visualize [OpenSeaMap](http://openseamap.org/) data on an Android device using [Mapsforge](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/). Since I need to do this in a disconnected manner (think boat out to sea) I need to generate a .map file using the Mapsforge Osmosis plugin, however to be able to do that I need a .osm file of the OpenSeaMap data.

Can anyone point to where I might find one or some other way to proceed?

Comment: There is already and Android SeaMap App - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.rulex.seamap not saying you shouldn't create your own app - but worth looking at.

Comment: That app does look nice, but it's online only; not much use when you're off-shore :)

Comment: Have a look at Oruxmaps or Oruxmaps Blue for android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the main OSM website, all the data you need is there, but isn't rendered in any of the standard styles. The tag you are looking for is `seamark`.

For instance, zooming in on a part of the [Solent](http://www.openstreetmap.org/?lat=50.80781&lon=-1.28795&zoom=15&layers=M) reveals nothing. But if you choose Edit|Browse <s>(you'll need an OSM login)</s>, a few spots show up in the water. Clicking on one of these gives us the goodies.

Downloading the data for this area as OSM XML, I can find data such as this:

```xml
<node id="672436827" lat="50.8070813" lon="-1.2841124" user="malcolmh" uid="128186" visible="true" version="11" changeset="9107813" timestamp="2011-08-23T21:22:36Z">
  <tag k="seamark:buoy_cardinal:category" v="north"/>
  <tag k="seamark:buoy_cardinal:colour" v="black;yellow"/>
  <tag k="seamark:buoy_cardinal:colour_pattern" v="horizontal"/>
  <tag k="seamark:buoy_cardinal:shape" v="pillar"/>
  <tag k="seamark:light:character" v="VQ"/>
  <tag k="seamark:light:colour" v="white"/>
  <tag k="seamark:name" v="Calshot"/>
  <tag k="seamark:topmark:colour" v="black"/>
  <tag k="seamark:topmark:shape" v="2 cones up"/>
  <tag k="seamark:type" v="buoy_cardinal"/>
</node>
```

Knowing this, you can download either one of the country, continental, or world datasets, and filter out just nodes with at least one `seamark` tag.

The biggest issue is one of styling; OpenSeaMap has a bunch of different symbols that are extra to the standard OSM lot, but I'm sure they're all available with a bit of asking around, although I'm sure Ian that you're capable of creating your own!

Comment: If you don't have a OSM login - go to Edit on http://www.openstreetmap.org/?lat=50.80781&lon=-1.28795&zoom=15&layers=M and click 'Browse Map Data' reveals the 'goodies' points info

Comment: I stand corrected! For some reason it didn't let me browse until I had logged in; maybe I wasn't zoomed in far enough...

Comment: *recommend all GISse users to have a OSM login...

Comment: thanks - I should have thought to look in the data file :-)

Comment: :) I'd be interested in what you come up with, if you're able to post the data somewhere.